# Copy and paste information based on matching IDs where one sheet has rows in the pivot table

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that allows me to copy and paste thousands of rows of information based on matching IDs. However the code does not seem to run well in a pivot table. In sheet 4, the IDs are put into a pivot table while in sheet 1 the IDs and the information are not in pivot table (Both IDs in sheet 4 and 1 are in the same column which is column A). However, the IDs appeared more than once in sheet 1. Thus, when i try to run the code, it gave an error that said `Cannot enter a null value as an item or field name in pivot table report" on the line 'rngTracker.Value = arrT` found below.

```
Sub Sample()

    Dim rngTracker As Range
    Dim rngMaster As Range
    Dim arrT, arrM
    Dim dict As Object, r As Long, tmp

    With Workbooks("FAST_Aug2015_Segment_Out_V1.xlsm")
        Set rngTracker = .Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A5:D43000")
        Set rngMaster = .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:C200000")
    End With

    'get values in arrays
    arrT = rngTracker.Value
    arrM = rngMaster.Value

    'load the dictionary
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For r = 1 To UBound(arrT, 1)
        dict(arrT(r, 1)) = r
    Next r

    'map between the two arrays using the dictionary
    For r = 1 To UBound(arrM, 1)
        tmp = arrM(r, 1)
        If dict.exists(tmp) Then 
         arrT(dict(tmp), 4) = arrM(r, 3)  
        End If
    Next r

    rngTracker.Value = arrT 'Error shown on this line' 

End Sub
```

Above is the code that i have and gave error as mention above. Would appreciate any help. Thank you. :) Below is the image of the pivot table in sheet 4. The column header called "Acc Seg" is not part of the pivot table but it is where the data will be paste from sheet 1 when both IDs in sheet 4 and sheet 1 matched.
[image]

Comment: Try assigning `arrT` only if arrM(1, 1) contains a valid value: if arrM(1, 1) doesn't exist in dictionary set `arrT(dict(tmp), 4) = "No Title"` (for i=1 only)

Comment: Hi did what you told me to do. The code run but it does not copy and paste any information from sheet 1 column 3 to sheet 4 column 4, is there any other alternative code? @paulbica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Sample()
    Const T As Long = 43000
    Const M As Long = 200000

    Dim arrT1 As Variant, arrM1 As Variant, rngT2 As Range
    Dim arrT2 As Variant, arrM2 As Variant, dict As Object, r As Long

    With Workbooks("TEST2.xlsm")    'get values in arrays
        Set rngT2 = .Sheets("Sheet4").Range("D5:D" & T)
        arrM1 = .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & M)
        arrM2 = .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C" & M)
        arrT1 = .Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A5:A" & T)
        arrT2 = rngT2
    End With

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For r = 1 To UBound(arrT1)      'load the dictionary
        dict(arrT1(r, 1)) = r
    Next r

    For r = 1 To UBound(arrM1, 1)   'map between the arrays using the dictionary
        If dict.exists(arrM1(r, 1)) Then arrT2(dict(arrM1(r, 1)), 1) = arrM2(r, 1)
    Next r

    rngT2 = arrT2
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried changing it but it still gave the same error on the line 'rngTracker.Value = arrT' @paulbica

Comment: I made an edit. Also, please set a breackpoint on line `rngTracker.Value = arrT`, open the Immediate window and type `? arrT(1, 4)` - what's the result after you press Enter?

Comment: Sorry, i type in the '? arrT(1,4)' and it says 21

Comment: Hi it still give the same error found on line 'rngTracker.Value= arrT' even when i used the code you have edited @paulbica

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89537/discussion-between-paul-bica-and-nabilah).

Comment: I changed it but it still gave the same error on the same line @paulbica

Comment: The latest edit works with the test file. Make sure you set the 2 constants at the top according to the last row on each each sheet of the the original file (`T As Long = ` **`43000`** and `M As Long = ` **`200000`**)

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your help! it works! :) @paulbica